# Cohen-Macaulay ring without non-trivial idempotent is homomorphic image of Noetherian domain?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, krull-dimension, cohen-macaulay

Let $R$ be a [Cohen-Macaulay ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohen%E2%80%93Macaulay_ring) with no non-trivial idempotent element. Then is it true that there is a Noetherian domain $S$ such that $R\cong S/I$ for some ideal $I$ of $S$ ?

If this is not true in general, what if we also assume $R$ has finite Krull-dimension ?

MOTIVATION: A theorem of Hungerford https://msp.org/pjm/1968/25-3/pjm-v25-n3-p11-p.pdf   says that every PIR is a homomorphic image of a direct product of finitely many PID s. So I was thinking about the same question for special kind of Noetherian rings

Comment: Can you motivate the question a little bit?